# Why is this script for removing comments leaving an empty line when I only select the first line?

Tags: rust, command-line

This script removes comments from code:

```
use anyhow::{Context, Result};
use std::io::{self, Read};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_to_string(&mut buffer)
        .with_context(|| "Failed to read from stdin")?;

    let modified_buffer = buffer
        .lines()
        .map(|line| {
            if line.trim().starts_with("//") {
                // If the line is a comment, return an empty string
                String::new()
            } else if let Some(pos) = line.find("//") {
                // If there's an inline comment, return the line up to the comment
                line[..pos].trim().to_string()
            } else {
                // If there's no comment, return the line as is
                line.to_string()
            }
        })
        .filter(|line| !line.is_empty()) // Remove empty lines resulting from full line comments
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .join("\n");

    println!("{}", modified_buffer);

    Ok(())
}
```

If I select all the lines (e.g. in a text editor and pipe the result):

```
// This is a comment
x = 1 // This is a comment
```

And run the script, all the comments will be deleted and no undesired new lines will remain:

```
x = 1
```

But if I only select the first line and run the script, an empty line will remain on top of the second line:

```
[There is an undesirable new line here]
x = 1 // This is a comment
```

Why is this, and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by select the first line?

Comment: Wouldn't this also butcher `x = "https://this-is.not-a.com/ment"`?

Comment: @trust_nickol If I select the line in a text editor and pipe the result to the script.

Comment: @pmf Good catch. I'll add some logic to handle that.

Comment: It will also remove indentation for lines that include a comment, e.g. "`____x = 1 // This is a comment`" will become "`x = 1`" without the leading spaces.

Comment: @Jmb [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0299ca9125098628d0a3c199b34bc598) version won't remove indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is not entirely clear but by

> But if I only select the first line and run the script

I assume you're only feeding that one line to the script's stdin, and substituting with the output, and you get a newline.

That's from the `println!`, which as its name indicates always terminates with a newline, so if you remove all the lines... you end up with a single empty line anyway.

This is difficult to suppress, because `Lines` loses data: you don't know whether the input ended with a newline or not (let alone which), so you will always have incorrect edge cases, you'll end up with either extra newlines or missing newlines.

In that case, it might be a better idea to use the lower-level `read_line` which includes the trailing newline.

That would also fix the current issue where your script removes empty lines or lines which only contain whitespace.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=775fc300e57f9f979a7eee36cd375257)? As far as I can tell, it solved the issue. But if I use `print` instead of `println` in my original code, the issue is gone too ... what's the difference?

Comment: Your new code is the same as the old one, pretty much: you're still using the lines iterator not `read_lines`. The problem is thus the same: `lines` removes the trailing newline, and you're further removing leading whitespace (and would be removing trailing newlines if there were any) by trimming contents. This means you're un-indenting intented code, and adding trailing newlines where there were none e.g. try running your script by only selecting the front half of a line (or selecting multiple lines and ending in the middle of one).

Comment: Though at a fundamental level your script will always break somewhere  as you're not parsing the input, thus you don't handle `//` inside string or block comments (and their interaction with trigraphs if C), preprocessor (if C), ...

Comment: I think you meant [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f1ee70a05422b3f89ae97600529ef0b0)? But I think it'll still break in some situations because I'm not parsing the input, right?

Comment: Yep. This should preserve more of the source, but I don't think you can resolve 100% of cases without the ability to guess the language and parse it for real. Although if you're only ever using this script from an interactive context (e.g. macos services or similar) "good enough" is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not certain when an empty line should be kept or discarded, depending on whether it was originally only made of a comment or not, here is a solution with the three possibilities.

This does not involve allocating new strings for the lines to be kept.
Moreover, it provides an iterator, then does not even need the allocation of a vector, in case the purpose is to iterate over the relevant lines (without necessarily storing them).

It preserves indentation but, as mentioned in several comments, it is not robust if the comment mark can appear in the text to be kept (it really depends on the grammar of the language to be dealt with).

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum EmptyRemoval {
    Never,
    Comments,
    Always,
}

fn meaningful_lines<'a>(
    input: &'a str,
    comment_mark: &'a str,
    removal: EmptyRemoval,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a str> + 'a {
    input.lines().filter_map(move |mut line| {
        let found = if let Some(pos) = line.find(comment_mark) {
            line = &line[..pos];
            true
        } else {
            false
        };
        match removal {
            EmptyRemoval::Never => {}
            EmptyRemoval::Comments => {
                if found && line.trim().is_empty() {
                    return None;
                }
            }
            EmptyRemoval::Always => {
                if line.trim().is_empty() {
                    return None;
                }
            }
        }
        Some(line)
    })
}

fn meaningful_lines_vec<'a>(
    input: &'a str,
    comment_mark: &'a str,
    removal: EmptyRemoval,
) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    meaningful_lines(input, comment_mark, removal).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let input = "// this line contains only comments
something on the left
    // this line too, but the next is intentionally left empty

    now it is indented // and followed by a comment";
    println!("{}", input);
    for removal in [
        EmptyRemoval::Never,
        EmptyRemoval::Comments,
        EmptyRemoval::Always,
    ] {
        println!("======== removal = {:?} ========", removal);
        for (i, l) in meaningful_lines(input, "//", removal).enumerate() {
            println!("{}: {:?}", i, l);
        }
        println!("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        println!("{}", meaningful_lines_vec(input, "//", removal).join("\n"));
    }
}
```

```
// this line contains only comments
something on the left
    // this line too, but the next is intentionally left empty

    now it is indented // and followed by a comment
======== removal = Never ========
0: ""
1: "something on the left"
2: "    "
3: ""
4: "    now it is indented "
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

something on the left


    now it is indented
======== removal = Comments ========
0: "something on the left"
1: ""
2: "    now it is indented "
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
something on the left

    now it is indented
======== removal = Always ========
0: "something on the left"
1: "    now it is indented "
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
something on the left
    now it is indented
```

Comment: I [tried](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cfccbe628ec58ce12d0c995ae207ad8c) your code with stdin. It's not preserving the empty lines that are not comments.

Comment: @wyc Ah? I thought it was the intention (removing empty lines as well).

Comment: Ha, I want to remove comments from code while leaving the code as it is.

Comment: @wyc I extended the solution in consequence, in order to choose the preferred behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example! I'll check it out.